# stopping execution of other requests in php

Tags: php

I have a booking system and I need to check that an availability exists then make a booking in php code. I can't have this code interrupted by other requests coming into the server. will flock work to satisfy this

Comment: `flock` is only advisory and is known to be quirky on some filesystems and platforms. See the comment section in the PHP manual. `flock` will only work reliably when all code accessing that file checks the flock prior to accessing the file, e.g it depends on the developer to make that check. a script or process not checking the flock can still alter the file.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't really clear but you could try: 
         exit();